# Magento 2: How to change config value within one process / request?

Tags: magento2, configuration, cache, testing, integration-test

For integration tests purposes I need to set a different config value to a single config directive. However the `configInterface` always returns the value which was set as the first one.

Code of the test:

```
class FooTest extends AbstractTestCase
{

    public function testFoo()
    {
        $this->setConfig('cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock', 0);

        ...
    }

    public function testBar()
    {
        $this->setConfig('cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock', 1);

        ...
    }

    private function setConfig($path, $value)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $model */
        $model = $this->getObjectManager()->create('Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config');
        $model->saveConfig($path, $value, 'default', 0);

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList */
        $cacheTypeList = $this->getObjectManager()->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
        $cacheTypeList->cleanType('config');
    }

    /** @return \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface */
    protected function getObjectManager()
    {
        return Bootstrap::getObjectManager();
    }

}
```

Code of the config value fetching within my extension:

```
class ConfigHelper
{
    private $configInterface;

    public function __construct(Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $configInterface)
    {
        $this->configInterface = $configInterface;
    }

    public function getShowOutOfStock($storeId = null)
    {
        return (bool) $this->configInterface->getValue('cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    }
}
```

The value fetched by `ConfigHelper` is always the one which is set in `testFoo()` method. The value set in `testBar()` method is saved to DB, but value returned by `getShowOutOfStock()` is always the first one.

I'm wondering how to modify the `setConfig()` method to invalidate the internal Magento cache and to fetch the real value.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magento integration test framework provides an annotation for config values, which is sufficient in most cases.

```
/**
 * @magentoConfigFixture current_store cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock 0
 */
public function testFoo()

/**
 * @magentoConfigFixture current_store cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock 1
 */
public function testBar()
```

You can also set the value for a specific store, or the default value, as I described here: https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2016/09/magento2-integration-tests-magentoconfigfixture/

> Set default value 42 for configuration path x/y/z:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @magentoConfigFixture default/x/y/z 42
>  */
> ```
>
> Set store specific value 42 for configuration path x/y/z in store with
>   code store1
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @magentoConfigFixture store1_store x/y/z 42
>  */
> ```
>
> Set store specific value 42 for configuration path x/y/z in current
>   store (i.e. default store)
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @magentoConfigFixture current_store x/y/z 42
>  */
> ```
>
> These are all possible formats. The first parameter **must** end with
>   `_store` or be ommitted. And if it is omitted, the path **must** start with `default/`, otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, works like a charm! However when I used @magentoConfigFixture annotation to set show_out_of_stock value, other config values set previously with setConfig() value don't work anymore - return NULL. Anyway, I updated the setConfig method with code from the fixture and it works great now. Thanks again!